# Do properties of NSObjects inside an NSArray change or do they have to be added again to the NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Does the code below change the **value** of the **item** that is inside the **_items** array?

```
CustomItem *item = _items.lastObject;

item.value = @"something";

[self saveItemsToDisk];
```

Or do I have to remove the **item** and add it again to the array?

```
CustomItem *item = _items.lastObject;

item.value = @"something";

[_items removeObject:_items.lastObject];

[_items addObject:item];

[self saveItemsToDisk];
```

Comment: First option should work. @Vulkan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will change the value of the item in the array, you don't need to add it again.

Answer (score 0):

No your don't need to remove the array. it will change the value